# Why does OpenURI return a 404, when the parsed URL works fine in browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I'm trying to screen-scrape a URL containing special characters like the Danish character `'ø'`.

The URL is:

```
url = "http://www.zara.com/dk/da/dame/tilbehør/tilbehør/stribet-hue-c271008p2195502.html"
```

In order to have OpenURI recognize it as a valid URL, I do:

```
url = Addressable::URI.parse(url).normalize.to_s
```

and parse it with:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
```

which returns:

```
OpenURI::HTTPError: 404 Not Found
```

I have no clue why OpenURI returns a 404, because the normalized URL works fine in a browser.

Why this is the case and what I have to do to fix it?

Comment: That works fine for me - i get a normal Nokogiri doc back.

Comment: @MaxWilliams - this is very strange. I get a 404 every time.

Comment: Maybe it's a nokogiri version issue.  I'm using v1.4.2

Comment: One thing i notice is that the website automatically redirects that url to `http://www.zara.com/?go=http%3A//www.zara.com/share/dame/tilbeh%25C3%25B8r/tilbeh%25C3%25B8r/stribet-hue-c271008p2195502.html` but it returns a 200 (rather than a 302 which is the normal redirect code) (tested with Curl). I'm guessing they changed their url schema to shove everything through the `go` parameter instead of using REST style nested paths.  I don't know if that has anything to do with your problem though.

Comment: I wonder if it does something different for requests from Denmark?  (that would be weird but not unheard of).  Where are you located?

Comment: With curl I also get a 200 response. Strange. I'm using `nokogiri` v 1.5.11 but I think the problem is with `open-uri`? I'm located in Denmark, but it seems that the response depends on how I access the url.

Comment: I get `"http://www.zara.com/dk/da/dame/tilbeh%C3%B8r/tilbeh%C3%B8r/stribet-hue-c271008p2195502.html"` for the result of your second line, what do you get?

Comment: @MaxWilliams - I get the exact same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that the problem was with the server of the URL I was trying to parse. They rejected the default User-Agent used by OpenURI.

From the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/OpenURI.html) on OpenURI, it says that additional header fields can be specified by an optional hash argument:

```
open("http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/",
  "User-Agent" => "Ruby/#{RUBY_VERSION}",
  "From" => "foo@bar.invalid",
  "Referer" => "http://www.ruby-lang.org/") {|f|
  # ...
}
```

I just used a different User-Agent and everything worked fine.

Comment: What did you end up using? I'm having the same problems with zara as well :)

Comment: I used: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 12.433.216) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.105 Safari/534.30